# Whose​ faces are behind the Nimrod stickers on the cover of Green Day's "Nimrod"?

Tags: rock, artwork, alternative-rock, punk

I googled a lot but couldn't find who's faces are behind the Nimrod stickers.
Are they some popular faces?

[image: here is the official Nimrod album art by Green day]

Comment: Google found a claim they're Eisenhower & Roosevelt, but I've not found any accredited confirmation

Comment: Haven't you seen music videos popping triangles and eyes showing up

Comment: Yes. My initial answer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimrod_(album)):

> After three art directors were rejected by the band and pressing was
>   behind schedule, Green Day asked the help of Chris Bilheimer, a friend
>   of Armstrong who had done covers for another group signed by Warner
>   Bros. Records, R.E.M.. **Having just the album title to work on,
>   Bilheimer had some ideas, with the one that went through being
>   inspired by a photograph Bilheimer saw, where a politician’s poster
>   had had his face removed. He felt the image was "striking" and seemed
>   to fit the band by featuring "a typical middle-age male, corporate
>   politician American kind of guy, and someone had completely taken his
>   identity away through vandalism."** Following that line of thought,
>   **Bilheimer took an encyclopedia picture of men in suits and ties and
>   put colored circles reading "nimrod." on their faces, "using that to
>   take away the people's identity".**

This information is sourced from the book [*Green Day: Rebels With a Cause* by Gillian G. Gaar](https://books.google.be/books/about/Green_Day.html?id=ZH63AAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y).

[Some on Reddit claim](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/h6xqi/til_the_people_on_the_cover_of_greendays_nimrod/c1t236i/) the people in the pictures are Banting and Best, the [discoverers of insulin](https://www.nobelprize.org/educational/medicine/insulin/discovery-insulin.html), but I haven't found any evidence that proves this definitely. Though other pictures for each of them do seem to correspond with the available facial features, and it makes sense that their pictures would be in an encyclopedia.

Answer (score 0):

The guy on the right is franklin gran Banting and I think the guy on the right is Charles best

Comment: Who was Franklin gran Banting? Charles best the Doctor?

Comment: @Jayden, could you add some sources to your answer, and as the OP requested, explain a bit more who the two of those men are?

Answer (score -1):

The faces on the cover of Green Day's "Nimrod" album are not specific individuals. The artwork is a collage of different images and faces, creating a distinctive and eclectic visual composition. The cover was designed by Chris Bilheimer, who has collaborated with Green Day on several of their album covers. The faces on "Nimrod" are a mix of vintage photographs and other elements, contributing to the album's unique aesthetic.